# Is getOrCreate function a good or a bad practice?

Tags: java, architecture

In my code (hypothetical) I'd like to use getOrCreate function. I pass the parameters and I either get a new entity or I get an existing entity from the database, if such entity exists.

From one point of view this is a wrong approach, because function should not do more than one thing. But from another point of view this is a single operation, that just does not have a proper word in English and I can reduce some duplicities in the code.

So is using this approach a good or a bad practice? And why?

Comment: Are you trying to create a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: The object, that implements the getOrCreate can be some kind of singleton like DAO. But this function does not return a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a get function.  You get an instance of the class.

It doesn't matter to the outside world how the get function works internally.

```
    public Object getObject(int key) {
        Object object = getObjectFromDatabase(key);
        if (object == null) {
            object = createObject(key);
            writeObjectToDataBase(key, object);
        }
        return object;
    }
```

Every method has one function.

Edited to add: Some people look at methods from the inside out.  That's what you need to do when you're writing the code for the method.  I recognized that my getObject method had to do several things to truly get an Object.

However, when you're **naming** the method, you look at a method from the outside.  Which is why my getObject method "gets an Object" (pretty short Javadoc description).  If you can't write a simple declarative sentence describing the function of your method, your method is possibly too complicated.

Comment: The getObject() is only supposed to get it. The outside world will not be knowing that it might also create a new object (Tight coupling of creation and retrieval of objects). This kind of design  can break if there are other methods performing other actions (mostly read) on the same db. For example if you have a getRecordCount() method which keeps count of number of records in a table locally. How will it know that "getObject()" has changed the DB's record count and it needs to read the count again?

Comment: @TheLostMind: getRecordCount() should do an SQL select count(*), which would return the correct count every time.  There should be a complete data access framework, but I made a simple method to illustrate the single responsibility principle.  My method is not tightly coupled.

Comment: ya.. Properly designed applications do minimize such dependencies. Still I think making retrieve and create 2 seperate methods makes the code loosely coupled..

Comment: @TheLostMind: And what happens when the programmer forgets to check for a null object after the get call?  NPE time.

Comment: Fair enough.. Your method provides a higher level of abstraction as well.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Never ever do this. I should not need to read your code to see you are internally "creating" a new instance on-demand in a GET method. Please name it "getOrCreate", it is also much more clear.

Comment: In the worst case,  you should name it `getOrCreate`, separation is better. It may doesn't matter for the caller how to get it. But it matters if you have created a new one(side-effect). if there is nothing to get, a method named getObject should tell the caller the fact, especially for public API. By creating `TryGet`, null object pattern or using the `None` concept in FP.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on many factors. For example you might keep a local cache for some tables. Now, if you call getOrCreate(someValue) on that table, then You will have to know whether you created it or just retrieved it . Because you might need to flush and reload the cache (by making another read operation).

You might have other dependencies which might cause significant problems later on.

Though I don't completely say that this is a bad practice, I think its better to seperate your concerns.

You could do something like -

```
if(searchForRecord()==null)
 {
  addRecord();
 }
```

Advantage of this approach : You will always know the state and behaviour of your system (what is happening).

Singleton pattern is a totally different thing. You always get `ONLY ONE OBJECT`. And creation of that object is handled internally and is private to the Singleton class. `You DONT need to know whether you get a new object or the old one because it doesn't matter to you`.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of functional programming, `create` has side effects, whereas `get` has not. The name of a function should show people if this function includes side effect or not, without requires looking into the function body. Thus, `getOrCreate` is ambiguous with regards to side effects. I think it is not a good practice.

Additionally, I found many `getOrCreate(user)` in a code where it seems that more than 99% of the time, there is a user to get. A better approach in this context would be that we check if the user exists, if not, an exception should be raised.